# To identify string counts of particular value

Tags: java

I have data in this format:

```
MainCode|SideCode|Family.
```

The actual data appears as below

```
990337|6953  |REGULAR_ENTREE
990337|990274|REGULAR_ENTREE 
8287  |5     |REGULAR_ENTREE
8287  |8266  |FRIES
```

## Case 1

```
990337|6953  |REGULAR_ENTREE
990337|990274|REGULAR_ENTREE/BF_ENTREE
```

If two families are similar (in this case we have both as "ENTREES ") , I don't have to read the main item code (990337). All these values are strings only.

## Case 2

```
8287|5   |REGULAR_ENTREE
8287|8266|FRIES
```

If two families are different (in this case we have both as "REGULAR_ENTREE " and "FRIES") , I need to read the main item code (8287). All these values are strings only.

Can any one help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you will be processing entries two at a time, and then comparing the strings to determine "similarity" in some way before doing some further processing.

Assuming your entries are always input this way, you can split on the "|" character to get your entries into two arrays, like this:

```
String[] entryA = "990337|6953|REGULAR_ENTREE".split("|");
String[] entryB = "990337|990274|REGULAR_ENTREE/BF_ENTREE".split("|");
```

Then you can check entryA[2] against entryB[2] for similarity (how you determine similarity is unclear from your question though) before deciding if you care about the "main item codes" which will be in entryA[0] and entryB[0].

Answer (score 0):

You could probably compare part of the string if it is 100% ENTREE, you could probably do something like this. Not sure if this is the best way to do it. Or you can do something like regex to compare the string if they

```
String Family ="ENTREE"
String testString ="990337|6953|REGULAR_ENTREE";
int string_length=testString.length();
String compare=testString.substring(string_length-7,string_length-1);
//entree is a 6 letter word -1 because always start from 0
if(compare.equals(Family)
{
//have no idea what you want to do here
}
else
{
//compare the main Code
}
```